# JavaScript - For loop within a for loop triggering twice on button press

Tags: javascript, html, list, for-loop

I have a series of horizontal lists within one vertical list. Each list item has an ID 'cr-id-x_y' where x is the vertical list item index and y is the horizontal list item index. I have created a for loop within a for loop to determine which list item has been targeted. The problem I'm having is the button presses seem to be firing twice (i.e. I'm seeing "Hello world" printed to the console twice on a button press). Please can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  for (let x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      if (
        e.target.closest(`#cr-id-${x}_${i}`) &&
        (e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON" ||
          e.target.parentElement.nodeName == "BUTTON")
      ) {
        console.log("Hello world");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do you select the closest element by ID? Each ID is supposed to be unique across the DOM, you can select it directly without `.closest()` from anything

Comment: Besides, by doing `closest(\`#cr-id-${x}_${i}\`)` inside a 30x loop inside a 100x loop, you are seeking _three thousand times_ the closest element, on EACH click of a button! And you are not even breaking any of these two loops after your element is found, so all 3000 loops are done all the way on each click. Certainly there's a way to be far, far less resource intensive, because your CPU must be on its knees. Like click event listeners?

Answer (score 4):

From the code you posted, it is not possible to guess why it is firing twice, but actually there is no need to loop at all. When you delegate like you do, you should be able to interrogate the clicked target - for example like this

```
document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target; // or if nested e.target.closest('button'), then use tgt in the next if
  if (tgt.tagName==="BUTTON") {
    const someParent = tgt.closest('someElementThatMightHaveCRId');
    if(someParent.id && someParent.id.startsWith('cr-id-')) {                
      console.log("Hello world",someParent.id);
    }
  }
})
```